# Evaluating and modifying theano tensors when stuff is on GPU

Tags: theano, deep-learning

I am seriously stuck with something for ages now. I need some help.

I am running a theano conv network on GPU.
The network has a loss function as such

def mse(x, t):
    return T.mean((x - t) ** 2)

Here x is the predicted value of a rectified liner unit and t is the expected value.

Now for a particular learning problem I am trying to modify the function such that I want to threshold the value of x. So essentially something simple as this

x[x>ts] = ts

But I am really struggling with this. I tried so many things

`ts = 0.91
    Y = T.vector()
    #x_update = (x, T.set_subtensor(x[(x > ts).eval()], Y))
    #f = function([Y], updates=[x_update])
    #v=np.empty(len((x > ts).eval()))
    #v.fill(ts)
    #f(v)
    #x.shape.eval()
    x_arr = x.flatten()
    print type(x_arr)
    print type(t)
    print type(x)
    #print T.shape(x_arr).eval()
    #print x.shape.eval()
    #print x_arr.shape.eval()
    #print t.shape.eval()
    #print x.eval()
    #print x_arr.get_value()
    #x_newarr = x_arr.eval()
    #x_newarr[x_newarr>ts] = ts
    #x = T.shared(x_newarr)
    return T.mean((x - t) ** 2)`

Apart from the three prints, which all print `<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable' >` everything else gives me error. 
So I am at my wits end how to do this simple stuff.
Is it because this stuff is on GPU ?

I did test the code on local python prompt, by constructing a numpy array and converting it into a tensor shared variable. The different stuff above works. 
But I am conscious that the type is theano.tensor.sharedvar.TensorSharedVariable and not theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable.

I would really appreciate if some one gives me a helping hand here.

Regards

Comment: I understand the variable x coming in is not a shared variable. So I cannot use get_value(). But even eval() fails on it. I get a big stack dump with the main error being "theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: A variable that is an input to the graph was neither provided as an input to the function nor given a value ...."

Comment: the full stack dump can be seen here https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the answer to this question given by pascal at
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/cNnvw2rUHc8

The failures are correct because the input values are not being provided at the time the function is being called, since it is symbolic.

The answer is to use T.minimum(x,threshold)